# setting shebang for python scripts with python path

Tags: python, pythonpath, shebang, env

I have a script for which I am trying to set up shebang so that I execute 
`./script.py` instead of `python script.py`. This works for me when it is the topmost line of my script

`#!/usr/bin/env python`. This uses `env.`

when I tried to do change this,
`#/usr/local/lib/python2.7`, I get this error message

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

when I checked my python version, it is

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version
'2.7.3 (default, Jun 21 2013, 13:45:37) \n[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)]'
>>>
```

and sys.path gives `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/*`. Although I do not see anything specific for `python2.7.3`.

can you guide me as how to set up using pythonpath instead of env.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shebang line should contain the actual python interpreter executable, not just a path to your python install. Probably can find the one you're looking for with `which python`

Comment: that worked!, but is there a difference between pythonpath and exectuable for python interpreter?

Comment: Yes. [PYTHONPATH](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) is used to append to the search path for modules.

Answer (score 3):

`which python` on your command line should give you the path to the shebang line you need.